# Proof of Translation Invariance of Brownian motion by Durrett

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Below is the proof of the translation invariance of a one dimensional Brownian motion starting at the origin, given by Durrett in Probability Theory and Examples. However, the proof only shows independence, and I don't see how $\{B_t-B_0:t\ge 0\}$ has the same distribution as a Brownian motion with $B_0=0$ as stated in the theorem. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain this part to me.

[image]

Comment: Just before this "Proposition" there are three properties listed. Property b) shows that the distributions of the increments are independent of $s$, hence you may choose $s=0$ and $B_0=0$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @JimmyR. I'm actually not sure what the author means by distribution here. Does he simply refer to the distribution of the increments of Brownian motion as in (b), in which case the result is trivial. I was wondering if there were a more generalized concept of a distribution of random processes.